# Compiling views when publishing asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, publishing

Is is possible to compile asp.net mvc views into one assemply when publishing web project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [ASP.NET Merge tool (Aspnet_merge.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397866.aspx) and Web Deployment Projects **(** **UPDATED:** `Aspnet_merge.exe` came with Windows SDK components when you installing Visual Studio 2008 - look at "%Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin" folder **)**. These links may be interesting to you:

- [How Do I: Use MSBuild to Automate the ASP.NET Compiler and Merge Utilities](http://www.bestechvideos.com/2008/08/23/how-do-i-use-msbuild-to-automate-the-asp-net-compiler-and-merge-utilities)
- [Managing ASP.NET Precompiled Output for Deployment Using the aspnet_merge.exe Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479044.aspx)

**UPDATED:**

In ASP.NET MVC projects there is `<MvcBuildViews>true/false</MvcBuildViews>` property which enables compiling Views in AfterBuild target. But it does not compile your project in one assembly. You should use ASP.NET Merge tool or Web Deployment Projects.

Comment: i used web deployment projects but it wasn't working as it supposed to

Comment: You could try aspnet_merge.exe -o OutputAssemblyName.dll "path to your compiled project". It works well on my projects